# I am married and currently being sponsored. I have a taxation number when filing taxes. How much HST rebate will my family receive?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate

I am married and currently being sponsored. I have a taxation number when filing taxes. How much HST rebate will my family receive?

Answer (score 2):

If you were a resident of Canada on December 31, 2009 and filed a 2009 tax return, you are treated like anyone else and should get the benefit accordingly, subject to regular eligibility criteria.  So, if you would otherwise qualify as a family, you'll get the family benefit amount.

If you weren't yet resident in Canada at that date, here's some information from the Ontario Ministry of Revenue's FAQ:  [Are there any special rules that apply to new immigrants to Ontario?](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_eligibility.html#Q24).  Excerpt:

> If you were not a resident of Canada
>   on December 31, 2009 and did not file
>   a 2009 income tax return, **you must
>   submit a 2009 statement of world
>   income to the [CRA](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/cntct/menu-eng.html) to be eligible for
>   the 2010 OSTTB payments.** If you
>   immigrated to Canada during 2009 and
>   filed a 2009 income tax return, the
>   CRA may request additional information
>   to ensure eligibility and benefit
>   amounts are accurately calculated.
>
> ...
>
> You must also meet all other
>   eligibility criteria outlined in [Q3](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_eligibility.html#Q3),
>   including **being resident in Ontario on
>   the specified dates.**   *[being May 31, 2010, for the first transition payment; emphasis mine.]*